# Swift: Merge Array of dictionaries with duplicate key but unique values

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift5

I have a array of dictionaries which contains same key but different values. I want to merge these dictionaries and add all the values of same keys just like below:

```
var arrayofDict = [["2019":"A"],["2019":"B"],["2019":"C"],["2018":"A"],["2018":"c"],["2017":"A"],["2017":"B"],["2017":"C"],["2016":"A"],["2015":"A"],["2015":"B"]]
```

expected result as an Array like:

```
   var newDict = [["2019":["A","B","C"]],["2018":["A","C"]],["2017":["A","B","C"]],["2016":["A"]],["2015":["A","B"]]]
```

Comment: "I have a array of dictionaries which contains same key but different values." I'm curious: Where did you get it from? Do you have control over that data?

Comment: Your *expected result* is actually an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This shows how to build a single dictionary.  Your "expected result" is an array.  Is this what you really expected or did you want an array?

You can iterate the dictionary items and build up the dictionary entries:

```
var arrayofDict = [["2019":"A"],["2019":"B"],["2019":"C"],["2018":"A"],["2018":"c"],["2017":"A"],["2017":"B"],["2017":"C"],["2016":"A"],["2015":"A"],["2015":"B"]]

var result = [String : [String]]()
for dict in arrayofDict {
    for (key, value) in dict {
        result[key, default: []].append(value)
    }
}

print(result)
```

> ```
> ["2016": ["A"], "2018": ["A", "c"], "2015": ["A", "B"], "2019": ["A", "B", "C"], "2017": ["A", "B", "C"]]
> ```

**Or, if you want an array:**

```
let result2 = result.map { [$0.key: $0.value] }
print(result2)
```

> ```
> [["2015": ["A", "B"]], ["2016": ["A"]], ["2019": ["A", "B", "C"]], ["2018": ["A", "c"]], ["2017": ["A", "B", "C"]]]
> ```

Comment: How to sort this in descending order of the year? and also sort values too? @vacawama

Comment: `let result2 = result.map { [$0.key: $0.value.sorted()] }; let result3 = result2.sorted(by: { $0.first!.key > $1.first!.key } )`

Answer (score 0):

as @vacawama in more functional way

```
let result = arrayofDict.reduce(into: [String:[String]]()) { (acc, d) in
    for key in d.keys {
        // don't worry to force unwrap d[key], if key exist, the value is not nil
        acc[key, default: []].append(d[key]!)
    }
}
```